# How to realize an camera overlay in phonegap app and save image

Tags: javascript, cordova, camera, overlay

-- Note: I really searched for hours to solve my problem, there are some solutions for android native and unanswered for phonegap --

I´ve got a phonegap app, made with notepad ++ and phonegap build. I want to use the camera api to overlay an image (for example a "png") in the camera view and save the made picture with the overlay in it.
A solution without the preview and just adding the "png" after taking the picture would be ok if nothing else comes up.

Is there a way to do this in pure javascript? Or maybe in another js framework for making apps?

thanks!!

Comment: did u get any??. even i am looking for same

Comment: i´m this far that i can open the camera (or load an image from gallery) and take a picture. After that i can drag and drop an element over the taken picture. But i´m still trying to save it in any way.. There are several approaches to do that, but all are  infuriatingly.